# Characteristic Classes of Fiber Bundles of Closed, Aspherical Manifolds with Isomorphic but Non-Congruent Group Extensions

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes, group-extensions

Suppose I have two closed, aspherical manifolds, $F$ and $B$, with $K = \pi_1(F)$ and $Q = \pi_1(B)$, and two group extensions $1 \to K \to G_1 \to Q \to 1$ and $1 \to K \to G_2 \to Q \to 1$ with $G_1$ and $G_2$ abstractly isomorphic but not congruent as group extensions. What can be said about 1) the characteristic classes of $F \hookrightarrow E_1 \twoheadrightarrow B$ and $F \hookrightarrow E_2 \twoheadrightarrow B$ and 2) whether $E_1$ and $E_2$ are homeomorphic as manifolds?

For instance, say I have fiber bundles $E_1^4$ and $E_2^4$ with base and fiber $T^2$ as follows.

Set $G_1 = \langle w_1, w_2, z_1, z_2\ |\ w_1w_2w_1^{-1}w_2^{-1}, w_1z_1w_1^{-1}z_1^{-1}, w_1z_2w_1^{-1}z_2^{-1}, w_2z_1w_2^{-1}z_1^{-1}, w_2z_2w_2^{-1}z_2^{-1}, (w_1^1w_2^4)^{-1}(z_1z_2z_1^{-1}z_2^{-1})\rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle u_1, u_2, z_1, z_2\ |\ u_1u_2u_1^{-1}u_2^{-1}, u_1z_1u_1^{-1}z_1^{-1}, u_1z_2u_1^{-1}z_2^{-1}, u_2z_1u_2^{-1}z_1^{-1}, u_2z_2u_2^{-1}z_2^{-1}, (u_1^2u_2^3)^{-1}(z_1z_2z_1^{-1}z_2^{-1})\rangle$.

Note $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, so $G_1$ and $G_2$ should be isomorphic:

In particualr, define $\Phi: G_1 \to G_2$ by starting with $\Phi(z_j) = z_j$. Then, note $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$, so send $\Phi(w_1) = u_1^{-2}u_2^{-1}$. Next, $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so let $\Phi(w_2) = u_1u_2$. This yields $\Phi(w_1w_2w_1^{-1}w_2^{-1}) = (u_1^{-2}u_2^{-1})(u_1u_2)(u_1^{-2}u_2^{-1})^{-1}(u_1u_2)^{-1} = e$. Similarly, $\Phi$ satifies the other slide relators involving the (u_i)'s and (z_j)'s. Finally, $\Phi(w_1w_2^4) = (u_1^{-2}u_2^{-1})(u_1u_2)^4 = (u_1^{-2}u_2^{-1})(u_1^4u_2^4) = u_1^2u_2^3$. So, $\Phi$ sends a relator of $G_1$ to a relator of $G_2$, and $\Phi$ is well-defined as a homomorphism of finitely-presented groups.

A similar argument, using the fact that $A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, as $\det(A) = -1$, shows $\Phi^{-1}$ is a well-defined homomorphism. A third simple calculation shows $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ are inverses of each other. Hence, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic.

But, I don't think they're congruent group extensions.

An outline of how to produce a fiber bundle from a group extension of the fundamental groups of the fiber and base spaces may be found here http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/mathjax/fiberBundle.html

Now, if we write $e^0_{n_0}$ for the element of $C^0(T^2)$ that sends $z_0$ to $n_0z_0$, $e^1_{(n_1,n_2)}$ for the element of $C^1(T^2)$ that sends $(z_1,z_2)$ to $n_1z_1+n_2z_2$, and $e^2_{n_3}$ for the element of $C^2(T^2)$ that sends $z_3$ to $n_3z_3$, then is the characteristic class of $E_1$ is $\eta_1 = e^1_{(1,1)} \smile e^1_{(1,4)}$ while the characteristic class of $E_2$ is $\eta_2 = e^1_{(1,2)} \smile e^1_{(1,3)} $?

Freedman and Quinn proved that closed, aspherical 4-manifolds with isomorphic polycyclic fundamental groups (which [$E_1$ and $E_2$ are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392636/dumb-question-is-my-group-polycyclic)) are homeomorphic.

So, I can't have the correct characteristic classes for the fiber bundles; what are the correct characteristic classes for the fiber bundles?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is relevant, but Freedman and Quinn work in the topological category and characteristic classes are often smooth invariants. I.e. is it possible that the manifolds are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic?

Comment: What characteristic classes are you referring to?

Comment: The characteristic classes of the fiber bundle.

Comment: Homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic manifolds have non-homeomorphic tangent bundles (as total spaces of fiber bundles); characteristic classes determine if the total spaces are homeomorphic or not https://twitter.com/DeadbeatJeffSDF/status/1497631574472499205

Comment: I disagree.  For example, as shown in R. De Sapio, Disc and sphere bundles over homotopy spheres, Math. Z. 107 (1968) 232-236., if $\Sigma^7$ is an exotic $7$-sphere, then $T\Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to $TS^7$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Do the characteristic classes of the tangent bundles of exotic spheres prove that the spheres are not diffeomorphic? If so, how do they do so?

Comment: No, they do not.  Specifically, the usual characteristic classes are Euler, Chern, Pontryagin, and Stiefel-Whitney.  Since Chern and Pontryagin classes live in even dimensional cohomology, the only possibly non-zero ones are Euler and S-W.  For Euler, the Euler class of the tangent bundle, when paired with the fundamental class, gives the Euler characteristic which is $0$ for any odd dimensional manifold.  And S-W classes have the property that the smallest non-vanish class is always in degree a power of $2$, so not $7$.  Thus, all char. classes vanish for both $T\Sigma$ and $TS^7$.

Comment: @JeffreyRolland: What do you mean by the characteristic class of a $T^2$-bundle? I have looked through *Characteristic Classes of $T^2$-bundles* by Morita and I can't see anything to indicate why there should an associated degree two integral cohomology class. In particular, we have $H^2(B\operatorname{Diff}^+(T^2); \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.